# Font change with different computers?

Tags: delphi

I have strange problem, after I finish working on my Delphi XE 8 Application I remove EXE fiels, DCU files and .map files and then zip and send to the test guy, the problem when same source code is opened in different PC the font size of UI controls change from Tahoma 8 to Tahoma 12 !! any idea why is that ?

Comment: Different DPI settings?

Comment: Yes that is right , different DPI change the font ? how to prevent that ?

Comment: Try turning `Scaled` to false on the form. http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TForm_Scaled.html

Comment: thanks  Blorgbeard I will check that.

Comment: You don't want to prevent this happening. If the user has set a high dpi, then you want your app to be scaled.

Comment: Thanks, I develop on dual monitors 23" and 24" with 150% dpi while my client still uses small desktop monitors and laptops monitors so any suggestions for the font name and size that I should use ? I currently use Tahoma 8 at my end